# ASP.Net page is not getting compiled

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the web applcation there is a .aspx page which `doesnt have the code behind file(.cs)`. it is in folder called `staticcontent` The below is the markup of aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
</head>
<body>    
 <form action='searchdata.aspx' method='post'>
 <input type='text' value='' id='searchText' />
 <button id='btnSearch'>Search</button>
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now i want to move this search text box to asp.net and register in this page.

However it is not getting compiled it seems.

It still render the syntax of user control only

```
<%@ Register Src="~/controls/EmpSearch.ascx" TagName="search" TagPrefix="emp" %>
<emp:search runat="server" ID="searchCtrl"></emp:search>
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<body>
This contains only static text and there is no dynamic data
Employee Search
<emp:search runat="server" ID="searchCtrl"></emp:search>
</body>
```

Tried using `<!--#include file="~/controls/EmpSearch.ascx"-->` no impact.

How come .aspx page is not compiled here.

The `.csproj has only <Content Include="StaticContent\Employee.aspx" />`

and doesn't have

```
<Compile Include="StaticContent\Employee.aspx.cs">
```

since it dont have code behind

Comment: if you have not codebehind , it's not compiled , please read the page life cycle !!!

Comment: @RameshRajendran code behind is optional only, read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163512.aspx) `ASP.NET, starting with version 1.0. As most Web developers should know by now, an ASP.NET page is typically written in one or two files: an .aspx markup file and, optionally, a code-behind file. The code-behind contains a class file written in any supported programming language, though typically Visual Basic or C#. The .aspx markup file contains HTML tags, ASP.NET control tags, and literals that form the structure of the page (it can also contain code).`

Answer (score 3):

Difficult to tell without the whole markup, but I would say that you might have some configuration that makes files stored in your `staticcontent` folder be treated as static content :-) and not be passed to asp.net for compilation/execution.

Have a look in your web.config or IIS at the configuration of the static content folder.

For information, this works on my dev server :

**WebForm1.aspx :**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
<%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControl1.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="WebUserControl1" %>
<html>
<head>   
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <uc1:WebUserControl1 runat="server" ID="WebUserControl1" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebUserControl1.ascx :**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"%>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbSearch"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Search"/>
```